# serializing from unmanaged structure to Stream in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, pointers, c++-cli

I am learning C++/CLI and stuck with a problem.
I have a header file that looks like

```
     typedef struct _DATA_INFO {     
       WORD ONE
       WORD TWO
       WORD THREE
      } DATA_INFO

    public ref class ManagedDataInfo
    {
     DATA_INFO* info;
     public ManagedDataInfo()
    {
     info=new DATA_INFO();
    }
    public void Write(Stream^ stream)
    {
//       stream.Write(content of info)
     // here i want to write content of info to stream
    }

}
```

Here I want to copy the content of **info** to the stream in the Write method but stuck how to do that.

Comment: Don't start identifiers with _Capital - they are reserved for the implentation. Just say 
struct DATA_INFO {WORD one; WORD two; WORD three;};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this method: [Marshal.StructureToPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr.aspx). This method will convert structure to sequence of bytes. Then you can write then using one of Stream.Write method.

Comment: Marshal.StructureToPtr copies managed object into preallocated unmanaged buffer. Stream.Write requires managed array, not unmanaged buffer.

Comment: @nitrocaster you are right you can later copy it from unmanaged realm to managed with Marshal.Copy (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx)

Comment: @nitrocaster actually my answer is kinda lame, you don't need those marshalling stuff for this simple case. Any serialization, even homemade like `'{0}{1}{2}'.Format(info.ONE, info.TWO, info.THREE)` is better.

Answer (score 1):

Stream provides a generic view of a sequence of bytes.
So that means you need to serialize the info object to a sequence of bytes.
To make byte array use  [Marshal.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx) method.
Hope this helps.